'auth_uri' does not exist in type 'JWTInput | ExternalAccountClientOptions'
I'm a newbie
I'm trying to deploy a Nextjs website to Vercel, everything works properly when I run and build it locally but then when the application is building on Vercel, I get this error from Vercel logs
Failed to compile.
./config/serverUtils.ts:53:17
Type error: Type '{ type: string; project_id: string; private_key_id: string; private_key: string; client_email: string; client_id: string; auth_uri: string; token_uri: string; auth_provider_x509_cert_url: string; client_x509_cert_url: string; universe_domain: string; }' is not assignable to type 'JWTInput | ExternalAccountClientOptions | undefined'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'auth_uri' does not exist in type 'JWTInput | ExternalAccountClientOptions'.
  51 |                 client_email: data.client_email,
  52 |                 client_id: data.client_id,
> 53 |                 auth_uri: data.auth_uri,
     |                 ^
  54 |                 token_uri: data.token_uri,
  55 |                 auth_provider_x509_cert_url: data.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
  56 |                 client_x509_cert_url: data.client_x509_cert_url,
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1

I'm confused as I checked the interface for JWTInput from googleapis and auth_uri exist in the interface, I don't know how to solve this error and would really appreciate help in solving the issue?
Below is the full code producing the error ./config/serverUtils.ts
"use server"
///This contains utility functions that are strictly for server based components

///Libraries -->
import { google } from "googleapis";
import { Readable } from "stream";

///Commencing the code
//Declaring the neccesary variables
const data = {
    type: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TYPE!,
    project_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PROJECT_ID!,
    private_key_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_KEY_ID!,
    private_key: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_KEY!.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),//process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
    //private_key: JSON.parse(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_PRIVATE_KEY!),
    client_email: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_EMAIL!,
    client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_ID!,
    auth_uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_URI!,
    token_uri: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_TOKEN_URI!,
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL!,
    client_x509_cert_url: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL!,
    universe_domain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_UNIVERSE_DOMAIN!,
}
//console.log("Google Credentials: ", GoogleCredentials)

///This function allows one to perform CRUD operation using Google Drive
class GoogleDriveCRUD {
    private oauth2client
    private drive

    constructor() {
        this.oauth2client = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
            credentials: {
                type: data.type,
                project_id: data.project_id,
                private_key_id: data.private_key_id,
                private_key: data.private_key,//process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
                client_email: data.client_email,
                client_id: data.client_id,
                auth_uri: data.auth_uri,
                token_uri: data.token_uri,
                auth_provider_x509_cert_url: data.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
                client_x509_cert_url: data.client_x509_cert_url,
                universe_domain: data.universe_domain,
            },
            scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"],
        });
        //this.oauth2client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: refreshToken })
        this.drive = google.drive({
            version: "v3",
            auth: this.oauth2client
        })
    }

    //This function is used to add a file to GDrive
    public async addFile(file: File, folderId: string | void) {
        try {
            const fileBuffer = file.stream();
            //const mimeType = mime.getType(file.name);


            const fileMetadata = {
                name: file.name, // The name of the file to be uploaded
                parents: folderId ? [folderId] : undefined, // The ID of the folder where the file should be uploaded
                mimeType: file.type,
            };
        
            const media = {
                mimeType: file.type,//'application/octet-stream',
                body: Readable.from(fileBuffer),
               //body: fileBuffer
            };

            const response = await this.drive.files.create({
                requestBody: fileMetadata,
                media: media,
                fields: "id, imageMediaMetadata",
            })
            
            console.log("Response 1: ", response)
            //console.log("Response 1: ", response.imageMediaMetadata)
            return response.data
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }

    //This function helps delete a file from GDrive
    public async deleteFile(driveId: string) {
        try {
            const response = await this.drive.files.delete({
                fileId: driveId
            })
            const res = await this.drive.files.get({
                fileId: ""
            })
            console.log(response)
            //console.log("Response: ", response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}

I have tried browsing and haven't found anything helpful, Please I would really appreciate any help in solving the bug. Thanks!

can you please remove or comment out these properties and try:
auth_uri: data.auth_uri,
token_uri: data.token_uri,
auth_provider_x509_cert_url: data.auth_provider_x509_cert_url,
client_x509_cert_url: data.client_x509_cert_url,
universe_domain: data.universe_domain,
`

